# Why is this not sending the enter key? [Python]

Tags: python, keyboard, keyboard-events

Why does it not send the enter key? I want it to type the message and then press enter to send it but the enter key is never pressed?

```
import keyboard, time     

while True:

    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
        keyboard.write("This text will be sent.")
        keyboard.press('enter')
        

    if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
        break
```

Comment: What is `keyboard`?  That's not a standard python module.

Comment: Solved it myself, needed a time buffer in between the sends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed a time buffer

```
import keyboard, time     

while True:

    if keyboard.is_pressed('ctrl'):
        keyboard.write("This text will be sent.")
        time.sleep(.1)
        keyboard.send('enter')
        
    if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
        break
```